# editor with some requirements

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, ajax, controls

Q:

I ask about free editors (controls), but i wanna a light one not heavy like **AJAX editor** ,i will use 4 or 5 editors in the page so i don't want my page to be heavy, and one more thing ,i find **CKEditor** , it is free and light but doesn't allow the (Read only) property..

any control or suggestion will be great .

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

definitely WidgEditor, it is the lightest yet quite powerful editor that I know of:

http://themaninblue.com/experiment/widgEditor/

Answer (score 1):

Try TinyMCE in simple mode :

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/